# Error when i try to download themes or icon

Tags: kubuntu

When i try to download a theme desktop or an icon package or something else (plasmoid), the window give me this error

> Unwknown error of API of collaboration service.

So I cannot download anything about plasma.
Can anyone give me some advice?

P.S. I'm italian, sorry for my english, I try to translate the error message so it can be different in "real english".

Thanks in advance
-Marco

Answer (score 0):

**Down for maintenance**

The 'Get Hot New Stuff': http://newstuff.kde.org is drawing stuff from the KDE-Look, KDE-Apps etc.

[image]

The KDE-Look, KDE-Apps, etc are down - there is an announcement:

> We are down for maintenance.
>
> Sorry for the inconvenience. We'll be back up as soon as possible.
>   Please try again later.

http://kde-apps.org/ :

[image]